# Reemplazar varias cadenas al mismo tiempo con función JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function strong(){
        var element = document.getElementById("decode");
        var value = element.textContent || "";
        var regex = /\*([a-zA-Z\d\w\s]+)\*/gi;
        element.innerHTML = value.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
    } strong();
```

```html
<div id="decode">
*Lorem ipsum dolor* sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Vestibulum aliquet justo id lobortis varius tortor leo tristique nulla volutpat maximus arcu urna viverra nisl Duis nec ultrices lacus.\r\n\r\nCurabitur vehicula convallis diam, a pellentesque velit efficitur ac. 
</div>
```

La función que cumple es convertir la oración encerrada en strong, ahí funciona perfectamente.
Lo que quiero es que también reemplace `\r\n` por un salto de linea `<br/>` pero no me funciona, ya intenté de este modo:

```
function strong(){
    var element = document.getElementById("newsfordecostrong");
    var value = element.textContent || "";
    var regex = /\*([a-zA-Z\d\w\s]+)\*/gi;
    element.innerHTML = value.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
    element.innerHTML = value.replace('\r\n', "<br/>"); // Se supone que aquí se haría el salto de linea.

}
strong();
```

Pero tampoco funciona, agradezco sus respuestas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te falta escapar el `\r` y el `\n`, encerrarlo en una expresión regular en lugar de tenerlo como cadena y por último añadir como modificador `g` para que remplace todas las ocurrencias.

Ten cuidado también cuando encadenes reemplazamientos, tienes que ir aculumulándolos en una variable y al final asignarlo a `element.innerHTML`. De la forma en que lo tenías, el primer reemplazamiento se machacaba con el segundo.

```js
function strong() {
    var element = document.getElementById("decode");
    var value = element.textContent || "";
    var regex = /\*([a-zA-Z\d\w\s]+)\*/gi;
    value = value.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
    value = value.replace(/\\r\\n/g, "<br/>");
    element.innerHTML = value; 
}

strong();
```

```html
<div id="decode">
    *Lorem ipsum dolor* sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Vestibulum aliquet justo id lobortis varius tortor leo tristique nulla volutpat maximus arcu urna viverra nisl Duis nec ultrices lacus.\r\n\r\nCurabitur vehicula convallis diam, a pellentesque velit efficitur ac. 
</div>
```